# How to stop Latex from inserting $ in my URLs?

Tags: math-mode, errors, urls

When I type this

```
\footnote{ http://www.cems.uvm.edu/~tlakoba/math337/notes_12.pdf. Page 3.}
```

LaTeX inputs `$ $` in for me when I do not want them. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: If you don't want to use \url as Sigur mentoined, you can simply escape the _ by typing `\_` this just prints the _.

Comment: @Dave, well done. But the problem would be with the tilde.

Comment: I think the expedient response deserves and accept, so maybe don't close it now it's done with.

Comment: @user27182 Closing doesn’t take any merits from the answer given, it’s just a valuable tool for managing the knowledge in this site by indicating that this question has been asked (and answered) before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the underline. Use the command `\url{}` from the `url` package.

```
\usepackage{url}

\footnote{\url{http://www.cems.uvm.edu/~tlakoba/math337/notes_12.pdf}, page 3.}
```